# How to filter dataset by number of rows of specific group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a dataset:

```
id     value
a1      14
a1      2
a1      34
a1      11
a1      78
b1      11
b1      9
b1      6
```

I want to filter that dataset by number if rows for each group, to make it no higher than 4. So desired output will be:

```
id     value
a1      14
a1      2
a1      34
a1      11
b1      11
b1      9
b1      6
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby.head`:

```py
out = df.groupby('id').head(4)
```

If you have pandas >=1.4.0, then you can use `groupby.nth` with slicing as well:

```py
out = df.groupby('id').nth[:4]
```

Output

```py
   id  value
0  a1     14
1  a1      2
2  a1     34
3  a1     11
5  b1     11
6  b1      9
7  b1      6
```